# How to handle error.VCollectionNotAvailableException: Collection down after opening. (10) in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, verity

I am using ColdFusion 9, with create a verity collection name 'shopColl'. I create a task schedule to call a CFM file to do indexing this collection every 5 minutes.

but I found this error when I try to refresh index in collection:

```
An error occurred while performing an operation in the Search Engine library.; DETAIL:The collection is not available.: com.verity.coll.VCollectionNotAvailableException: Collection down after opening. (10)
```

Could you help me how to solve this? the process seems correct before until this night.

The code below, is in CFM file that task schedule will invoke in routine.

```
<cfprocessingdirective  suppresswhitespace="true">

<cftry>
    <!--- pull the content --->
    <cfquery datasource="shop" name="shop.getContent">
        SELECT * 
        FROM shop
    </cfquery>


    <!--- update collection --->
    <cflock name="cfindex_lock" type="exclusive" timeout="30">

    <cfindex collection="shopColl"
             action="refresh" 
             type="custom"
             query="shop.getContent"
             key="id"
             title="title"
             body="title,description" >

    </cflock>

    <!--- Log information about document change --->
    <cflog file="updateStatus" application="No" 
      type="information" 
      text="MESSAGE: Eso shop collection updated; TIME: #now()#">


    <cfreturn true />

<cfcatch type="any">
    <!--- Log information about error --->
    <cflog file="updateStatus" application="No" 
      type="error" 
      text="MESSAGE: error in updating index -- #cfcatch.message#; DETAIL:#cfcatch.detail# TIME: #now()#">
    <cfreturn false />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
</cfprocessingdirective>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it outside of being a task to see how long it takes.  If it takes longer than 5 minutes, it could be deadlocking with the scheduled task.

Comment: Hi, jarofclay. I tried to run CFM with browser directly but ColdFusion still log the same error. Could you give me more any suggestion?

Comment: -Turn off the scheduled task so it doesn't run while you are testing
-Restart the Verity service
-Try running your script again (not as scheduled) and note the time

If that is still giving you the same error, try running a repair with the executable in the k2\_nti40\bin directory:

"mkvdk.exe -collection <collectionpath> -repair"